# select case for refresh_dropdown_list?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible for a `dropdownlist` to have a "select case" feature?

My `combobox`'es value lists are based in `refresh_dropdownlist` which is on different sheet called "List"

If you're going to ask why I made this kind of sheet, it's because we always have new machines and lines so it will be easy for them to add new machine codes etc., without coding or calling me. And sheet list is linked to charts and formula for counting, "sum if" etc.

this is my list for combobox
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIV3Q.jpg)

my current code

```
Sub Refresh_DropDown_List()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
 

Dim i As Integer


'''' combobox for Machine
Me.cmb_machine.Clear
Me.cmb_machine.AddItem ""
    
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("C:C"))
    Me.cmb_machine.AddItem sh.Range("C" & i).Value
Next i

'''' combobox for Line
Me.cmb_line.Clear
Me.cmb_line.AddItem ""

For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("D:D"))
    Me.cmb_line.AddItem sh.Range("D" & i).Value
Next i
```

what i wanted to happen is when the cmb_line.value is for ex. "L1" then cmb_machine.value will only display range "C2:C28" and so on and so forth for other lines.

Comment: Please never post pictures of code. Copy - paste as text and format as code.

Comment: im sorry about that. i was trying to paste it earlier but kees on showing error.

Comment: How do you plan on identifying the correct rows? For example, for `L1` the lines start with `LINE 1` so you can use *if the line starts with LINE 1 Then* but you have to somehow assign `LINE1` to `L1` i.e you need another list (a 'begins with' column).

Comment: L1 refers to Line Location. which compose 28 mahinces with different codes. my problem is, I put all machines in 1 column a total of 300+. so is it possible or is there a code like case select or select range (C2:28) with out separating or making another column for list?

Comment: Assume drop down = combobox, you can set your range of values within an array to reference or reference the range of values directly... you don't need to `addItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want use a dynamic range, e.g.:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Sheets(1)
        ComboBox1.List = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)).Value
        ComboBox2.List = .Range(Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Tested with simple data:

[image]

Note that it's `Range().Value` to set the `ComboBox.List`.

Comment: thanks. this code helped me.